# stylelint-webpack-plugin not watching scss files

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack, postcss, stylelint

I have this webpack config that I'm using to process and lint my js and scss.

```
    var path = require('path');
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    var CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
    var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
    var StyleLintPlugin = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin');
    var PostCssLoader = require('postcss-loader');

    var sassLoaders = [
    'css-loader',
    'postcss-loader',
    'sass-loader'
    ]

    module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-source-map',
    entry: {
        global: "./src"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        chunkFilename: "[id].chunk.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js/,
            loaders: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallback: 'style-loader', use: sassLoaders.join('!')})
        }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css"),
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        filename: "common.js",
        name: "global"
        }),
        new StyleLintPlugin({
        context: "src",
        configFile: '.stylelintrc',
        files: '**/*.scss',
        failOnError: false,
        quiet: false,
        syntax: 'scss'
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options: {
                postcss: []
            }
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        modules: [ path.join(__dirname, './src') ],
        extensions: ['.js', '.scss', '.css']
    }
    }
```

In my src folder I have an index.js and a styles.scss.

Running `webpack` properly lints my index.js and styles.scss files. However, running `webpack --watch` only re-lints when I change my js file. It does not seem to be watching my styles.scss file for updates.

Is there anything I need to be doing to make the webpack watch work properly with the scss files as well?

Comment: Also looking after this :(